# No DB Error Numbers in Codeigniter

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, error-handling, oracle11g, codeigniter-2

I am using Codeigniter connected to an oracle 11g db with the provided driver. I am getting a database error with my query, but Codeigniter is not showing any error numbers :/
Any ideas?

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: It happens on any database query I have tried.

Comment: what is the error message that CI gives?

Comment: [blog]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16325631/no-db-error-numbers-in-codeigniter#new-answer "check it this"